# How to number groups in a pandas df column

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I have tried solutions from similar examples, but I have not managed to make it work. I have a df looking like this:

```
              S
2017-07-21   -1.0
2017-07-24   -1.0
2017-07-25   -1.0
2017-07-26    1.0
2017-07-27    1.0
2017-07-28    1.0
2017-07-31   -1.0
2017-08-01    1.0
2017-08-02    1.0
2017-08-03   -1.0
2017-08-04   -1.0
2017-08-07   -1.0
2017-08-08    1.0
2017-08-09    1.0
2017-08-10    1.0
```

I need to number every change in column values, and the output should be:

```
              S     n
2017-07-21   -1.0   1
2017-07-24   -1.0   1
2017-07-25   -1.0   1
2017-07-26    1.0   2
2017-07-27    1.0   2
2017-07-28    1.0   2
2017-07-31   -1.0   3
2017-08-01    1.0   4
2017-08-02    1.0   4
2017-08-03   -1.0   5
2017-08-04   -1.0   5
2017-08-07   -1.0   5
2017-08-08    1.0   6
2017-08-09    1.0   6
2017-08-10    1.0   6
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `shift` to check consecutive numbers.

```
In [2521]: (df.S != df.S.shift()).cumsum()
Out[2521]:
2017-07-21    1
2017-07-24    1
2017-07-25    1
2017-07-26    2
2017-07-27    2
2017-07-28    2
2017-07-31    3
2017-08-01    4
2017-08-02    4
2017-08-03    5
2017-08-04    5
2017-08-07    5
2017-08-08    6
2017-08-09    6
2017-08-10    6
Name: S, dtype: int32
```

Assign like

```
In [2522]: df['n'] = (df.S != df.S.shift()).cumsum()

In [2523]: df
Out[2523]:
              S  n
2017-07-21 -1.0  1
2017-07-24 -1.0  1
2017-07-25 -1.0  1
2017-07-26  1.0  2
2017-07-27  1.0  2
2017-07-28  1.0  2
2017-07-31 -1.0  3
2017-08-01  1.0  4
2017-08-02  1.0  4
2017-08-03 -1.0  5
2017-08-04 -1.0  5
2017-08-07 -1.0  5
2017-08-08  1.0  6
2017-08-09  1.0  6
2017-08-10  1.0  6
```

**Or** use `diff`

```
In [2527]: df.S.diff().ne(0).cumsum()
Out[2527]:
2017-07-21    1
2017-07-24    1
2017-07-25    1
2017-07-26    2
2017-07-27    2
2017-07-28    2
2017-07-31    3
2017-08-01    4
2017-08-02    4
2017-08-03    5
2017-08-04    5
2017-08-07    5
2017-08-08    6
2017-08-09    6
2017-08-10    6
Name: S, dtype: int32
```

---

Details

```
In [2524]: df.S != df.S.shift()
Out[2524]:
2017-07-21     True
2017-07-24    False
2017-07-25    False
2017-07-26     True
2017-07-27    False
2017-07-28    False
2017-07-31     True
2017-08-01     True
2017-08-02    False
2017-08-03     True
2017-08-04    False
2017-08-07    False
2017-08-08     True
2017-08-09    False
2017-08-10    False
Name: S, dtype: bool
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot.